# MYSQL to PostgreSQL data migration

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.3

Below is an excerpt of the metadata of the Customers table that is retrieved via a script I'm running. The script calls a service which retrieves the metadata and data from a MYSQL database via JSON, it then converts the metadata (e.g data types, column constraints) into POSTGRESQL readable syntax and loads the data into a Postgresql database.
Please note that primary key column `id` is of TYPE BYTEA:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BYTEA
```

Metadata of the Customers table before conversion:

```
('columns before conversion', [[u'id', u'binary(16)', u'NO', u'PRI', None, u''], 
[u'person_id', u'varchar(255)', u'NO', u'', None, u''], [u'ident_id', u'varchar(255)', u'NO', u'', None, u''],[u'seller_id', u'binary(16)', u'YES', u'MUL', None, u''], [u'inserted_at', u'datetime', u'NO', u'', None, u'']])
```

This is the converted metadata to POSTGRESQL readable syntax using sqlalchemy:

```
[OrderedDict([('name', u'id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.BYTEA'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', True), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'person_id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'ident_id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'seller_id'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Unicode'>), ('nullable', True), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)]), OrderedDict([('name', u'inserted_at'), ('type_', <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.DateTime'>), ('nullable', False), ('default', None), ('autoincrement', False), ('primary_key', False), ('unique', False)])])
```

I've also converted the values in the `id column` to `Base64` based on Boris's comment below:

```
                df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: base64.b64encode(x))
```

However, I'm still receiving an error when loading the data:

```
(psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "customers_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(aion}{�}�HQDAS�987) already exists
```

I'm at a loss here because the Customers table is dropped and created each day before the data is imported. The primary key column is a unique identifier so I'm puzzled where this error is coming from.

Any ideas or feedback who be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: So do you have the "binary" column in MySQL that is converted into "Unicode" PostgreSQL column? Maybe it is just converted incorrectly, making same unicode string for different source binary values? So you get few records imported in and then the primary key get's repeated raising the error.

Comment: yes, at least in SQLAlchemy the type is converted to Unicode - when the table is created, however, i just checked and the actual data type in PostgreSQL is char var. So I need to check what the reason behind this is..definitely seems like this could be the issue.

Comment: I think the binary filed should be mapped to the PostgreSQL's binary field (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html) or you need to use some safe binary-to-text conversion (like base64 encoding), otherwise you can't safely map binary data to text.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `binary` column in MySQL that is converted into `Unicode` PostgreSQL column.

I think it is just being converted incorrectly, making same unicode string for different source binary values. So you get few records imported in and then the primary key get's repeated raising the error.

It is better to use the binary field on the PostgreSQL side (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html) or to use some safe binary-to-text conversion (like [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)).

Comment: thanks for this, see how I have adjusted the script but i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the `id` value has actually been changed? The value in the error is the same, while it should be very different from the original, for example `base64.b64encode(bytes('teststring', 'utf-8'))` outputs `b'dGVzdHN0cmluZw=='` - at least it should not have `�` signs anymore.

Comment: Yes, the values are now in the format of `Pe+/ve+/vRFl77+9Q`. I have not used the `bytes('teststring', 'utf-8')` conversion. Maybe i should?

Comment: No, I think your data is already has `bytes` type, I've just used it to convert string to bytes. So how the error looks like now, do you have something different instead of `(aion}{�}�HQDAS�987)`?

Comment: The error is `Error: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "customers_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(\x50652b2f72b2f76`)

Comment: Strange, is it really an unique column in MySQL then? Try loading the data in batches to see where it fails and then check, if there is actually the row with same id already. Then you can compare this rows in MySQL. I could provide more help if you created some minimal reproducible example, so I could debug it locally.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that and perhaps give you a reproducible sample

Comment: I'm testing a different table that also gave me the initial error, however, now after the conversion to `BYTEA` and `base64` the error is different: `Error: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "payments_idemp_key"
DETAIL:  Key (payments_idemp)=(df0221b3-ea82-41ef-ac6e-1028a421e92f) already exists.` Odd thing about this error is that there is only one record in the source database.

Comment: Strange indeed, and may indicate that you are looking at the wrong place - maybe the target table is not actually empty and the problem is that it's not actually being dropped/created?

Comment: No, I'm definitely dropped the entire Schema. And then re-creating the tables one by one.

Comment: The issue lies with the method of pagination when importing data into the DWH. We assume the sequence is numeric, in this case its binary. I'll need to find a way of paginating binary values if that even makes sense.